# QPX Express API - Lista de voôs

Tags: php, javascript, json, google

Estou tentando utilizar o QPX Express API para buscar lista de vôos, na documentação tem como passar os argumentos, mas não sei como usar, por exemplo:

Documentação:

> The simplest way to try out this API is to send it a POST request with curl. For >example, create a file named request.json with the following content (replace each >instance of YYYY-MM-DD with a date, which can be up to a year in the future.):

JSON:

```
{
  "request": {
    "passengers": {
      "adultCount": 1
    },
    "slice": [
      {
        "origin": "BOS",
        "destination": "LAX",
        "date": "YYYY-MM-DD"
      },
      {
        "origin": "LAX",
        "destination": "BOS",
        "date": "YYYY-MM-DD"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

A documentação diz isso:

> Then execute the following command from within the same directory as the above >request.json file. (As explained in Prerequisites, you must first obtain an API key.)
>
> curl -d @request.json --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=your_API_key_here

Onde executar este código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUÇÃO**

consegui depois de muita pesquisa pegar a lista de voôs usando qpxExpress

```
<?php 

$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=SUA-API-KEY";
$data_string = '{
                  "request": {
                    "passengers": {
                      "adultCount": 1
                    },
                    "slice": [
                      {
                        "origin": "MCO",
                        "destination": "GRU",
                        "date": "2015-01-23"
                      }
                    ],
                    "solutions": 2
                  }
                }';                                                                            
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch); // resultado!!!!
?>
```

obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente pra testar o `QPX Express API` usando curl você deve seguir esses passos:

1. **Criar um arquivo JSON chamado `request.json` com o conteúdo que você colocou na questão e salvar em um lugar que você lembre depois, lembrando que a documentação pede pra você alterar a data:**

*No meu caso eu coloquei a data de ida para (20 de Janeiro de 2015) e a data de volta para (27 de Janeiro de 2015)*

[image: request json]

2. **Acessar via `terminal/prompt` o local onde você salvou o arquivo criado e executar o commando:**

> curl -d @request.json --header "Content-Type: application/json"
>   https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=sua-API-Key

[image: curl]

3. **Como resposta você verá no terminal um código JSON com bastante informação a respeito do voo, segue trecho da resposta da API:**

[image: response]

---

*Considerações:*

- Você consegue uma API Key seguindo este tutorial no [próprio site da
  API](https://developers.google.com/qpx-express/v1/how-tos/authorizing).
- Outra maneira de testar a API (sem usar API Key e sem usar curl) é
  acessando a [DEMO que a API disponibiliza](https://qpx-express-demo.itasoftware.com/).

Comment: mas como posso pegar esses dados em json

Comment: tem como eu fazer usando PHP?